# How do you structure a multi function batch write with different databases (Firestore, Auth, Realtime)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have a Firebase Function that updates many things in different collections that are all related. I'd like to use batch write so that nothing is partially updated, all or nothing. But my problem is that each of these updates happen in different functions for example:

```
await update1(data) // update to firestore 
await update2(data) // update to firestore and realtime
await update3(data) // update to firestore and auth
```

I think I can pass in a reference to the batchWrite into each function? And then at the end of all the updates run batch.commit(). I think that'd work but the problem that comes up is some of these update functions update stuff inside of auth() and the realtime database. How can I also make those writes all or nothing with the Firestore writes? I had a thought of returning a callback function that executes the auth and realtime update which would be called on a successful batch.commit, but what if those fail...

How do you structure a multi function batch write with different databases (Firestore, Auth, Realtime)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to your first question

> I think I can pass in a reference to the batchWrite into each function?

Yes, you can pass the batch instance to multiple functions. As long as you remember to batch.commit() at the end it should work as expected.

Your second question

> How do you structure a multi function batch write with different databases (Firestore, Auth, Realtime)?

There is currently no way to execute a batch write across multiple Firebase products (eg RTDB, Firestore, etc).

To minimize the chance of failure you should perform your operations in a reliable environment, such as cloud functions as they have extremely low downtime. In most cases, if a cloud function fails partway through it's because of improper validation or error handling.